# Calling method on runtime without firing any event in angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on AngularJS+Html application. I want to call an event automatically as div created at runtime.

Div is created with `ng-repeat="obj in objList"`. As first div created with `{{obj.shortName}}` its corresponding div load the value from `vm.relatedLists`.
`vm.relatedLists` will be loaded based on `obj.shortName`

```
<div class="col-sm-8" ng-repeat="obj in objList">
    <div class="col-sm-2" ng-show="viewRule"><div class="col-sm-2" ng-if="obj.fullName !== '-'">{{obj.shortName}}</div><div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="obj !== '-'"></div></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="obj.fullName !== null"><input placeholder="{{obj.fullName}}" class="form-control"  id="field_obj{{obj.id}}" name="field_obj{{obj.id}}" type="text" ng-model="vm.details.obj"  uib-typeahead="reg.fullName for reg in vm.relatedLists | filter:{fullName:$viewValue} | limitTo:25" typeahead-editable="false" class="form-control"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-if="obj.fullName !== null && obj.fullName !== undefined && obj.fullName !== ''"> <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size: 16px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1" ng-if="obj.fullName !== null"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="vm.refresh('mpr',1)" ><i class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size: 16px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-12"><p></p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Method to be call on runtime creating div is :

```
function changeLoadLists(shortName){
    if (shortName!= undefined) {
        var chapterId='I';
        if (item == 'one' || item == 'two') {
            if (item == 'one'){
                id='I';
            }else{                                                        
                id='II';
            }
            vm.relatedLists = GetAllLists.query({
                id: id
            }, onListsSuccess);

        }
    }
}

function onListsSuccess(result) {
    vm.relatedLists = result;   
}
```

How to fire an event automatically as I have no click event or other event to be fired, it should load type ahead values with `vm.relatedLists` by passing shortName.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand you needance, but to achieve what you ask in the title you can use nginit attribute on your tag, take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Comment: I tried ng-init, but it won't work, I need to fire the event automatically as div created.

Comment: and you've tried tyo put the ng-init on you repeated div or the parent? can you write a fiddle? So that i can help you by modifiing it?

Comment: I am putting here : <div class="col-sm-2" ng-show="viewRule"><div class="col-sm-2" ng-if="obj.fullName !== '-'" ng-init="changeLoadLists(obj.shortName)">{{obj.shortName}}</div><div class="col-sm-4" ng-if="obj !== '-'"></div></div>

Comment: It normally would have work, what's item? Write a feedle so that i can help you.

Comment: It won't go to method if I write in ng-init.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by **`ng-init`** and make sure you use it with **`ng-if`** as it creates dom element only on condition `true`, unlike `ng-show` which just hides dom element.

See this [**fiddle** link](http://jsfiddle.net/87pz21mu/) and try to replace `ng-if with ng-show.` to see the difference

Comment: In your example you have one click of button to fire the next event, but in my case I need automatically to be fired the event.

Comment: Let consider if you can fire your store event automatically then next event will loading() will be fired.

Comment: yes I deliberately put that button to show the difference of `ng-if and show` in terms of loading, When your remove the them then it called as soon as div loads. [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt48w46r/)